# How can I transform results from lapply into a matrix in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix, lapply

I want to use lapply in R.

Furthermore my function looks like the following:

```
func_countries <- function(x){
      Country <- x
      Nrow <- nrow(data[which(data$country == x),])
      Res <- list(Country, Nrow)
      return(Res)}

Overview_countries <- unlist(lapply(countries_list, func_countries))
```

How can I get the result of lapply displayed into a matrix which I can use for further calculations? I tried the following but it wasn't helpful because numbers are not numeric plus I can't use for example '$' to select columns.

```
Overview_countries <- matrix(Overview_countries, nrow=2, dimnames=list(c('Country', 'Numb_obs')))
Overview_countries <- t(Overview_countries)
```

Comment: Instead of using  `$`, you can use `[[`.  Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output.  Also, if the 'Country' is not numieric, a data.frame output would be better as `matrix` can hold only a single class.  So, `Res <- data.frame(Country, Nrow)` in the function and use `do.call(rbind, lapply(countries_list, func_countires))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not necessarily the best one here; as @akrun said, a data  frame would seem more suitable than a matrix, and packages like `dplyr`and `data.table` can perform these aggregations more elegantly.

But to answer your question: you can use the `byrow` argument to get what you (probably) want.

I created a little vector `a` that should be similar to the output of the `unlist(lapply(` you use.

```
a <- list(list('Belgium',25), list('Holland', 89), list('UK', 784))
a <- unlist(a)

res <- matrix(a, nrow=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(NULL, c('Country', 'Numb_obs')))
```

Output:

```
     Country   Numb_obs
[1,] "Belgium" "25" 
[2,] "Holland" "89" 
[3,] "UK"      "784"
```